# How to pass a div position to a child element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass the click position through to a child element of a div.  In the following sample, I'm trying to pass the top and left co-ordinates of `my-div` through to the `handleClick()` function:

```
<div id="my-div">
    <div onclick={() => this.handleClick(this.offsetX, this.offsetY)} />
```

`offsetX`/`y` was my guess, but that doesn't seem to work.  Is it possible to take the co-ordinates of the *parent* item and pass them through to a function of the child element?

Comment: it sounds very anti-pattern since the control flow should remain uni-directional (top down). Your child elements could have their props changed according to the parent element's state instead.

Comment: Are you sure this is React?

Comment: Yes, it's React (although I suspect that makes no difference to the question).  I can see why you'd say it's an anti-pattern, but the parent div may be half way across the screen, so I need to know how many px the user has clicked from the start of the div.  clientX and pageX only give me the x value relative to the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do like this:

Function to handle the click:

```
 handleClick = e => {
    var rect = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect);
 };
```

Element you want to get the coordinates:

```
  <div id="parent">
      <div id="child" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}>
        try this
      </div>
   </div>
```

rect will be an object containing the coordinates relative to the document and the dimension of the parent of the div you clicked.

Then you can use them as you like.

Comment: Won't that give me the co-ordinates of the element that I click into ?  I'm actually trying to get the co-ordinates of the parent element, which may / will be different

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the question. I edited the answer. It should work this way.